# Spring Boot / Data JPA EntityScan recursive

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a lot of entity classes organized in subpackages of a base one.
can i somehow use the `@EntityScan` Annotation to scan for them recursively?

Per Example

```
package org.example.entity.letters
class A {}
class B {}

package org.example.entity.nums
class One {}
class Two {}
```

currently im specifying every subpackage explicitly

```
@EntityScan(basePackages={"org.example.entity.letters","org.example.entity.nums"})
```

is there a way to make this simpler?

like: (just imaginary)

```
@EntityScanRecursive("org.example.entity")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
@EntityScan(basePackages={"org.example.entity"})
```

is enough :D Why wouldn't you even try it?

Comment: oh god. was missing the basePackages -_- ty

Comment: i mean in my code. really thanks a lot. saved me hours